# Why do we need to specify the standard Lark lexer to be able to catch comment terminals?

Tags: python, lark-parser

I'm working on a Lark-based project where I need to be able to "catch" comments in the code being parsed.

However it doesn't work when using the standard lexer without explicitly specifying the standard lexer.

I have taken the second example from [the Lark recipes](https://lark-parser.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes/) and modified it to use the default parser and to parse C++-like one-line comments:

```
import lark

comments = []

grammar = r'''
start: INT*

COMMENT: "//" /[^\n]*/

%import common (INT, WS)
%ignore COMMENT
%ignore WS
'''

# This doesn't work, comments are not appended to the list
# parser = lark.Lark(grammar, lexer_callbacks={'COMMENT': comments.append})

# But this does work
parser = lark.Lark(grammar, lexer='standard', lexer_callbacks={'COMMENT': comments.append})

source = r'''
1 2 3  // hello
// world
4 5 6
'''

parser.parse(source)

print(comments)
```

If I don't have `lexer='standard'` the result is an empty list.

But shouldn't it already be using the `'standard'` lexer when one isn't explicitly specified? Is it a mistake in my code, or a possible bug in Lark?

---

Further experimentation seems to indicate that it's either the `'dynamic'` or `'dynamic_complete'` being used in the default case (`lexer` not specified).

Comment: From [the code](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/blob/87a18a098e306dbe0f4258732ad8944832dc4a39/lark/lark.py#L306), it seems that with the default `auto` value for the lexer and without specifying a parser or `postlex`, you should indeed get the standard lexer... it may be worth to step into the `Lark()` call and see what goes on in there exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Lark` supports different combinations of `parser` and `lexer`. Some support `lexer_callbacks`, some don't:

| parser | lexer | lexer_callbacks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| lalr | standard | Yes |
| lalr | contextual | Yes |
| earley | standard | Yes |
| earley | dynamic | No |
| earley | dynamic_complete | No |
| lalr | custom | (Maybe) |
| earley | custom | (Maybe) |

`lexer="auto"` selects a lexer depending on the parser: For `lalr` it selects `contextual`, for `earley` it selects `dynamic`. The default parser is `earley`, so without selecting `parser` or `lexer`, `lexer_callbacks` are not supported.

A [issue](https://github.com/lark-parser/lark/issues/386) in this regard was already opened and closed again.